# How to hide button after slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider with "next" and "previous"  buttons, "previous" button is hidden.

I want to hide "next" button when last slide is shown and show "previous" button after first transform of the slide.

Want to implement it in Javascript, can you please help me?

```
let next = document.querySelector('.btn_next_slide'),
prev = document.querySelector('.btn_prev_slide'),
line = document.querySelector('.product_slider_line'),
slides = document.getElementsByClassName('product_slider').length,
step = document.querySelector('.product_slider').clientWidth
count = 0;

next.onclick = ()=> {
    count ++;

    if (count >= slides-1) count = slides-2;
    line.style.transform = 'translate(' + `${- step * count}px)`;
};

prev.onclick = ()=> {
    count --;

    if (count <= 0) count = 0;
    line.style.transform = 'translate(' + `${- step * count}px)`;
};
```

Comment: Please add some example of your code to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JohannesWulf I've adde my js code for slider, hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function which updates the visibility after every slide-change.

```
let next = document.querySelector('.btn_next_slide'),
    prev = document.querySelector('.btn_prev_slide'),
    line = document.querySelector('.product_slider_line'),
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName('product_slider').length,
    step = document.querySelector('.product_slider').clientWidth,
    count = 0;

next.onclick = () => {
    count++;
    if (count >= slides - 1) count = slides - 2;
    line.style.transform = 'translate(' + `${- step * count}px)`;
    updateButtonVisibility();
};
prev.onclick = () => {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) count = 0;
    line.style.transform = 'translate(' + `${- step * count}px)`;
    updateButtonVisibility();
};

function updateButtonVisibility() {
    if (count === 0) {
        // first slide
        prev.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        next.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else if (count === slides - 2) {
        // last slide
        prev.style.visibility = 'visible';
        next.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        // medium slide
        prev.style.visibility = 'visible';
        next.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just 1 small correction  else if (count === slides - 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-carousel-button]');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // show the buttons because they can be hidden before
    buttons[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
    buttons[1].style.visibility = 'visible';
    const positionChange = button.dataset.carouselButton === 'next' ? 1 : -1;
    const photos = button
      .closest('[data-carousel]')
      .querySelector('[data-photos]');
    let activePhoto = photos.querySelector('[data-active]');
    let newPosition =
      [...photos.children].indexOf(activePhoto) + positionChange;

    photos.children[newPosition].dataset.active = true;
    delete activePhoto.dataset.active;
    // Check if active slide is the first one or the last one
    if (newPosition === 0) buttons[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    if (newPosition === photos.children.length - 1 && button === buttons[1])
      buttons[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).